# HP mini 210 too hot on lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, intel-graphics, hp, overheating

I have looked around the internet and have not found a solution to my overheating problem and thought I would ask you.

I'm relatively new to linux, but have converted my hp mini 210 into a lubuntu 14.04 machine. And things are running nicely here, except that the computer is running significantly warmer than when I ran windows 7.

I can't remember what processor / graphics card I have, and am not sure how to check this on lubuntu (any help here?) But a standard hp mini 210 has a 1.666Hz intel atom processor N450 and an Intel GMA 3150 graphics card.

Any ideas of how I can make my computer less hot?

Comment: Have you installed the latest Intel drivers?

Comment: i've done, apt-get update, and apt-get upgrade, but i'm not sure how to check my lastes drivers

Comment: Intel have an installer that can be downloaded as a deb; http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/intel-linux-graphics-driver-installer-1-0-5

Answer (score 0):

There are a few important things to factor in here.

First, Linux is going to use your hardware differently. That means the temperature will be different. It may do more stuff, use more power, have different default CPU speeds etc.

This is not a bad thing, it is just 'a' thing.

Second, Linux will not overheat your board. The kernel has built in protection. If your box gets to hot it will log a "Thermal Event" and then either shut down or adjust things to run cooler.

Third,  almost all boards have a thermal protection circuit that will turn off the computer  before any damage is done. You should not relay on this, as it is just a safety net but it's worth mentioning.

Last, Linux is very adjustable if you have a real need to run cooler (and it's not just to match windows) you can probably slow the CPU, speed up any fans, turn off some graphic features, or kill some CPU intensive processes. (Or maybe even run some hardware in a "power saver" mode that reduces the power it uses.)

My advise is, if it ain't broke don't fix it. Look in /var/log/messages and see if there are any thermal events, if there aren't and the computer is not crashing, then your fine and enjoy your new Linux box.

Comment: I totally get the whole different temp thing, makes sense. But there's no real point in having a laptop if it is uncomfortable to put on your lap.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post and recently found a possible solution.

A little back story...

My HP mini 210 I bought used at my local Goodwill Store for less than $50. Not expecting much from it (since it was used) I took it home. Everything appeared to work fine. Then I noticed that the battery only lasted for 2 hours unplugged and that it overheated causing the WiFi to be intermittent.

The first issue that I looked into was battery life. I came across an article that mentioned several tips, but one stood out to me. Remove the battery while plugged in. So I have been doing so for the last week.

Since I have been doing this I have noticed the following:

- No longer overheating
- Fan is quite
- WiFi appears to be working properly